# How can I reduce the size of a Subversion repository?

Tags: svn, diskspace

I have a pair of svn repositories which are significantly larger than others. They're not too big for svn, but they're taking a lot of disk space I'd rather be using for something else.

What strategies are available for reducing the disk use of svn repositories? I tried the "removing dead transactions" section [described here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html) but that didn't get me anywhere. What else should I try?

ETA: Is this question better asked on Server Fault?

Comment: @closers: Subversion is a tool used by developers. The other 5853 questions tagged svn confirm this is the place to ask. It makes no sense to fragment svn questions between here and ServerFault.

Comment: @Daenyeth: Trust me, I know. But as with most repositories (?) there are several users, and unilateral switches to `git` take time. I'm looking for a short-term mitigation. (That said, isn't "use git" sort of like answering a Windows question with "Buy a Mac"?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the used disk space is more important for you than the version history, then you could make a clean checkout and reimport your projects into a new repository. The old repositories could then be stored in a compressed archive.

If you don't want to lose the complete history, then this article might be interesting for you: [Delete parts of subversion history](http://robmayhew.com/delete-parts-of-subversion-history/)

Comment: You've hit on an interesting sticking point: is the history more important than the disk space, or not. I guess I was hoping there was some kind of `svnadmin compress-archive --pixie-dust` command I hadn't found in the documentation. If a clean check-out and re-commit is really the most effective way, then migrating the repos to git is probably the route we'll take.