# subversion rolling back Source Files based on commit date

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, rollback

I'm currently involved in a godawful mess at my work. There are ownership issues around intellectual property developed after a certain date. I have been instructed by a specialist intellectual property lawyer to not infringe on this intellectual property. In my mind the ideal way of dealing with this issue would be to discard all check-in's and everything attached to the check-ins such as comments made after a certain date.

At this stage doing a checkout of the SVN for files added/modified prior to this date and then starting a new repository is the only way I know of achieving this out come. Obviously this will destroy IP which has no ownership issues because commit logs and change records for the period prior will be lost.

What is the best way to remove the checkins after a certain date while preserving all information that existed prior to the ownership issues.

Sorry if this is posted in the incorrect section I couldn't find a better section to post.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Basically the same topic and answer: [How can I reduce the size of a Subversion repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3770914/256544)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a combination of `svnadmin dump` then `svnadmin load` into a newly created repository. Something like that should work:

```
svnadmin dump -r 1:last_rev /path/to/old/rep | svnadmin load /path/to/new/rep
```

Where `last_rev` is the last IP-problems-free revision.

Comment: I think `svnadmin` takes bare paths rather than URLs.

Comment: Thanks so much for that, I will give this a go tomorrow morning and let you know how it goes.

Comment: OK Guys, I used svnrdump dump ... to create a full.dump file which included all source up to the final problem fee revision.

I then tried tried unsuccessfully to use  svnrdump load to load the dump into the repository.

So I then tried successfully using svnadmin load to load the full.dump into the path of the repository on the server. This was successful and has removed the problem code, however I have still lost all the changelogs and the revision history has started at revision 1 again. This is going to be a problem. Would svnrdump load keep the revision and change history?

Comment: Why didn't you use svnadmin dump ? You don't have shell access to your server ? You need to load the dumped file into a NEW repository.

Comment: The svnadmin dump and svnadmin load commands listed above work and correctly reset the repositories. Thanks so much for everyone's help!

Problem Solved.